# SharePoint Communication Site image specifications

Tags: sharepoint-online

If I am able to see existing image sizes on a SharePoint webpage, I can crop my own images to work flawlessly. However, on Office 365 Modern sites, images must have limits on dimensions and filesizes.
Is there a master list of image specifications.

Answer (score 0):

With Image web part in the SharePoint Online modern page, you could resize images in the web part. But it still can’t see the size of the resize images.

Here's reference:[Image sizing and scaling in SharePoint modern pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-sizing-and-scaling-in-sharepoint-modern-pages-dc510065-b5a5-4654-bc94-e3ecbbb57d8d)